# React with Material UI Theming - Setup Global Color Variable

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I override default material-ui theme with customised global css? Also, how can we use HEX value of colours for setting up primary and secondary colour while theming?

App.js

I have root file App.js in which I have created custom theme and I need to apply external css say custom-style.css in my custom theme, to override the default styling of Material-UI. ( Struggling to get styling for form element colours for various state and button state colours, to be 
specific! )

Here is the code:

**App.js**

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({  
  palette: {
    primary: '#2765af',
    secondary: '#f56428',
  },
  status: {
    danger: 'orange',
  },
});

function App(){
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        ...
    <ThemeProvider>     
}
```

The HEX code is not allowed and throws compilation error. Also the customised CSS file ( custom-styles.css ) styles are overridden by the default styling, if I don't use theme object and add that file in App.js to try my luck.

Please help me.

Comment: Look at example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jp8yn0nr39

Comment: I don't want to use the predefined color panel of Material UI, instead use this particular color code. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-material-ui-typography-w6et9

Demo with Button custom color.
Theme color override by hex color in theme of App: index.js.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: "#d41252" },
    secondary: { main: "#F1B929" }, 
    type: "dark"
  }
});
```

Comment: Look at example, you see the result and simple code.

Comment: i updated the answer and link https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-material-ui-typography-w6et9